# which animation fits expandable container in flutter?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

How to make a container a new page by making it full screen with animation?
I have seen the animation widgets and I tried to do that with animation container but I failed.( the problem was I couldn't make it full screen and I couldn't define animation I want)

Regards

Animation showed 
[here](https://dribbble.com/shots/3812962-iPhone-X-Todo-Concept) in Dribbble while dragging the container up. 
( Doesn't matter dragging or tapping. just I want to know which tool should be used for the animation. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, the animation you are looking for is combination of `SlideTransition` and `ScaleTransition`.